# Python: Scrapy start_urls list able to handle .format()?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to parse a list of stocks so I am trying to format the end of my `start_urls` list so I can just add the symbol instead of the entire url.

Spider class with `start_urls` inside `stock_list` method:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    symbols = ["SCMP"]
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]     

def stock_list(stock):
    start_urls = []
    for symb in symbols:
        start_urls.append("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}&annual".format(symb))
    return start_urls

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    revenue = hxs.select('//td[@align="right"]')
    items = []
    for rev in revenue:
        item = DozenItem()
        item["Revenue"] = rev.xpath("./strong/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items[0:3]
```

It all runs correctly if I get rid of the `stock_list` and just do simple `start_urls` as normal, but as it currently is will not export more than an empty file.

Also, should I possibly try a `sys.arv` setup so that I would just type the stock symbol as an argument at the command line when I run `$ scrapy crawl dozen -o items.csv`???

Typically the shell prints out `2015-04-25 14:50:57-0400 [dozen] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=SCMP+Income+Statement&annual>` among the LOG/DEBUG printout, however does not currently include it, implying it isn't correctly formatting the `start_urls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a for loop, like this:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    stock = ["SCMP", "APPL", "GOOG"]
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    def stock_list(stock):
        start_urls = []
        for i in stock:            
            start_urls.append("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}".format(i))
        return start_urls
    start_urls = stock_list(stock)
```

Then assign the function call as I have at the bottom.

---

## UPDATE

Using Scrapy 0.24

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    symbols = ["SCMP"]
    name =  "yahoo"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]

    def stock_list(symbols):
        start_urls = []
        for symb in symbols:
            start_urls.append("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}&annual".format(symb))
        return start_urls
    start_urls = stock_list(symbols)

    def parse(self, response):
        revenue = Selector(response=response).xpath('//td[@align="right"]').extract()
        print(revenue)
```

You may want to tweak the xpath to get exactly what you want; it seems to be pulling back a fair amount of stuff. But I've tested this and the scraping is working as expected.

Comment: This is perfect and makes complete sense, yet exports an empty csv. I think the `.format()` is not working and the `{}` are just being included as the url....

Comment: @CharlesWatson Thanks, glad it helped. Have you defined your parse method and told it to extract anything? I don't see you mention anything about the actual scraping above.

Comment: I've added my parse method to the post.

Comment: I just realised, I think you're using the older version of Scrapy. If you can, upgrade and try what I add to the edit of my original answer. It won't be compatible with the older version, but I've tried it and know it's working in the latest release.

Comment: My shell says `Starting Scrapy 0.24.6`. Am I referencing old syntax somehow?

Comment: @CharlesWatson yeah I think so, just Google the official Scrapy documentation. Should be the latest docs.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way for implementing dynamic start URL's is to use `start_request()`.
Using `start_urls` is the preferred practice when you have a static list of starting URL's.

> **start_requests()** This method must return an iterable with the first
>   Requests to crawl for this spider.

Example:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    stock = ["SCMP", "APPL", "GOOG"]

    def start_requests(self):
        BASE_URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=BASE_URL.format(s)) for s in self.stock

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse the responses here
        pass
```

This way you also use a generator instead of a pre-generated list, which scales better in case of a large `stock`.

Comment: This is the preferred "pythonic" and "scrapic" way to approach the problem!

Comment: @alecxe "scrapic" -- that's a new one. I bet I'll use it again. =)

Comment: @elias so will I! There are so many things this word could be applied to :)

Comment: Indeed, using `start_urls` with multiple URL's, give random behaviour when crawling new pages. I didn't know about `start_requests`, and just implemented a new index, like: `start_urls = [my_urls[0]]` and then updating the index for every new page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by random behaviour, but if you are talking about the order of crawling, that is not a guarantee, because everything is happening asynchronously.